# how to insert dynamic table rows?

Tags: php, jquery

I need to create dynamical table rows and insert into database using php MySQL.

First query in the loop doesn't work and all the remain loop works fine.
I am unable to trace out. Thanks in advance

```html
$count = 1;
if(isset($_POST['byMonth']))
{
 
for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{
 echo $year = $_POST['year'.$i];echo '<br>';
    $month = $_POST['month'.$i];
     $actual = $_POST['amount'.$i];
      
   //$date = $_POST['entry'.$i];
  echo $que = "insert into worker_by_month(uid,year,month,actual_amount,date) VALUES ('".$uid."','".$year."','".$month."','".$actual."','".$entry."')";
 $mysqli->query($que);
  $count = $_POST['items'];
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML code? further have you checked is there any mysql/sytax error in the first iteration?

Comment: That starting $i=1 could be it if the data is indexed from zero. You never process the first `0` element.

Comment: You should consider prepared statements with parameters. SQL Injection... here's a cheat sheet https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet